# Присвоить начальное значение массиву false

Tags: android, массивы, kotlin

Есть метод в котором сэчу данные для моего `expandableList'a`

```
fun updateViewsContent(dataSet: List<BreakdownChartEntry>,
                       reportType: ReportType,
                       incomeSumm: Double,
                       expenseSumm: Double,
                       currencyCode: String) {
    this.dataSet = dataSet
    dataSet.forEach { visibilityArray.add(false) }
    this.reportType = reportType
    this.incomeSum = incomeSumm
    this.expenseSum = expenseSumm
    this.currencyCode = currencyCode
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Также создаю массив `var visibilityArray: MutableList<Boolean> = mutableListOf()`, в котором для каждого элемента по умолчанию присваиваю значения `false`.И всё вроде бы всё гуд, но как всегда есть маленькое НО!

Мой массив будет всегда **увеличиваться**, при вызове метода `updateViewsContent()`.

Собственно вопрос следующий, как можно присваивать изначально корректно значения `false` для моих данных? Или же как можно обойти момент `increment'ирования` моего массива.

Comment: Например, создавайте массив внутри `updateViewsContent`.

Comment: не совсем понял логику, которую вы хотите реализовать

Comment: `сэчу` - это как?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо где-то (решать вам, всего кода не вижу), либо в методе, либо перед его вызовом, или еще где, вместо этой неоптимальщины:

```
dataSet.forEach { visibilityArray.add(false) }
```

делать так:

```
var visibilityArray = Array<Boolean>(dataSet.size, { i -> false })
```

или так:

```
var visibilityArray = Array<Boolean>(dataSet.size, { i -> false }).toList()
```

или наконец так, если очень надо:

```
var visibilityArray = Array<Boolean>(dataSet.size, { i -> false }).toMutableList()
```

Comment: Переменная i тут в роли position'a выступает?

Comment: @Morozov, это индекс по массиву, в момент создания он заполняется значениями по умолчанию. Таким образом вы его можете инициализировать как угодно.

Comment: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/